# Resizing a View. Not working the way I planned

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview

I'm resizing a UIView and a UIScrollView based on the number of pixels that UITextViews are being moved.  I have all of the pixels being stored in `int` variables. At the end of my method to populate all of these text views I'm using this:

```
viewHeight += viewPixelsToBeAdded;
viewHeight -= viewPixelsToBeRemoved;
detailsView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, viewHeight);
realDetailsView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, viewHeight);
```

viewHeight is the constant view height which is 1475. I'm using `viewPixelsToBeAdded` and `viewPixelsToBeRemoved` to hold the total number of pixels that the view needs to be resized. When I use the above code... my scrollView (detailsView) just stops scrolling. Altogether.  I have my objects inside of a view. That view is inside of a scrollView.  Is there an easier way to go about resizing this stuff? Why does my scrollView stop scrolling when I increase or decrease its height? Any help would be greatly appreciated. I can post the entire populateLabels method if need be.  I kinda feel like I'm taking the long route with it anyway.

```
-(void) populateLabels {

NSString *noInfo = (@"No Information Available");
lblCgName.text = _Campground.campground;
NSString *cgLoc = _Campground.street1; 
NSString *cgCity = _Campground.city;
NSString *cgState = _Campground.state1;
NSString *cgCountry = _Campground.country;
NSString *cgZipPostal = _Campground.zipPostal;
cgLoc = [[cgLoc stringByAppendingString:@", "] stringByAppendingString:cgCity];
cgLoc = [[cgLoc stringByAppendingString:@", "] stringByAppendingString:cgState];
cgLoc = [[cgLoc stringByAppendingString:@", "] stringByAppendingString:cgCountry];
cgLoc = [[cgLoc stringByAppendingString:@" "] stringByAppendingString:cgZipPostal];
lblCgLoc.text = cgLoc;
double dRate = [_Campground.regRate1 doubleValue];
double dRate2 = [_Campground.regRate2 doubleValue];
NSString *rate = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"$%0.2f",dRate];
NSString *rate2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"$%0.2f",dRate2];
if ([rate2 isEqualToString:@"$0.00"]) {
    lblRate.text = rate;
} else {
    rate = [[rate stringByAppendingString:@" - "] stringByAppendingString:rate2];
    lblRate.text = rate;
}
double dPaRate = [_Campground.paRate1 doubleValue];
double dPaRate2 = [_Campground.paRate2 doubleValue];
NSString *paRate = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"$%0.2f",dPaRate];
NSString *paRate2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"$%0.2f",dPaRate2];
if ([paRate2 isEqualToString:@"$0.00"]) {
    lblPaRate.text = paRate;
} else {
    paRate = [[paRate stringByAppendingString:@" - "] stringByAppendingString:paRate2];
    lblPaRate.text = paRate;
}
lblLocal1.text = _Campground.localPhone1;
lblLocal2.text = _Campground.localPhone2;
lblTollFree.text = _Campground.tollFree;
lblFax.text = _Campground.fax;
lblEmail.text = _Campground.email;
lblWebsite.text = _Campground.website;
NSString *gps = _Campground.latitude;
NSString *longitude = _Campground.longitude;
gps = [[gps stringByAppendingString:@", "] stringByAppendingString:longitude];
lblGps.text = gps;

int viewHeight = 1475;
int textViewDefaultHeight = 128;
int newTextViewHeight = 0;
int highlightsPixelsRemoved = 0;
int highlightsPixelsAdded = 0;
int notesPixelsRemoved = 0;
int notesPixelsAdded = 0;
int directionsPixelsRemoved = 0;
int directionsPixelsAdded = 0;
int rentalsPixelsRemoved = 0;
int rentalsPixelsAdded = 0;
int viewPixelsToBeRemoved = 0;
int viewPixelsToBeAdded = 0;

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------    

txtHighlights.text = _Campground.highlights;
[self fitFrameToContent:txtHighlights];
newTextViewHeight = txtHighlights.contentSize.height;
if (newTextViewHeight > textViewDefaultHeight) {
    highlightsPixelsAdded = newTextViewHeight - textViewDefaultHeight;
    viewPixelsToBeAdded += highlightsPixelsAdded;
    txtTentsHead.frame = CGRectOffset(txtTentsHead.frame, 0, highlightsPixelsAdded);
    txtTents.frame = CGRectOffset(txtTents.frame, 0, highlightsPixelsAdded);
    txtNotesHead.frame = CGRectOffset(txtNotesHead.frame, 0, highlightsPixelsAdded);
    txtNotes.frame = CGRectOffset(txtNotes.frame, 0, highlightsPixelsAdded);
    txtDirectionsHead.frame = CGRectOffset(txtDirectionsHead.frame, 0, highlightsPixelsAdded);
    txtDirections.frame = CGRectOffset(txtDirections.frame, 0, highlightsPixelsAdded);
    txtRentalsHead.frame = CGRectOffset(txtRentalsHead.frame, 0, highlightsPixelsAdded);
    txtRentals.frame = CGRectOffset(txtRentals.frame, 0, highlightsPixelsAdded);


} else if (newTextViewHeight < textViewDefaultHeight) {
    highlightsPixelsRemoved = textViewDefaultHeight - newTextViewHeight;
    viewPixelsToBeRemoved += highlightsPixelsRemoved;
    txtTentsHead.frame = CGRectOffset(txtTentsHead.frame, 0, -highlightsPixelsRemoved);
    txtTents.frame = CGRectOffset(txtTents.frame, 0, -highlightsPixelsRemoved);
    txtNotesHead.frame = CGRectOffset(txtNotesHead.frame, 0, -highlightsPixelsRemoved);
    txtNotes.frame = CGRectOffset(txtNotes.frame, 0, -highlightsPixelsRemoved);
    txtDirectionsHead.frame = CGRectOffset(txtDirectionsHead.frame, 0, -highlightsPixelsRemoved);
    txtDirections.frame = CGRectOffset(txtDirections.frame, 0, -highlightsPixelsRemoved);
    txtRentalsHead.frame = CGRectOffset(txtRentalsHead.frame, 0, -highlightsPixelsRemoved);
    txtRentals.frame = CGRectOffset(txtRentals.frame, 0, -highlightsPixelsRemoved);

}   


//----------------------------------------------------------------------------    

txtTents.text = _Campground.tents;

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------    

txtNotes.text = _Campground.notes;
[self fitFrameToContent:txtNotes];
newTextViewHeight = txtNotes.contentSize.height;
if (newTextViewHeight > textViewDefaultHeight) {
    notesPixelsAdded = newTextViewHeight - textViewDefaultHeight;
    viewPixelsToBeAdded += notesPixelsAdded;

    txtDirectionsHead.frame = CGRectOffset(txtDirectionsHead.frame, 0, notesPixelsAdded);
    txtDirections.frame = CGRectOffset(txtDirections.frame, 0, notesPixelsAdded);
    txtRentalsHead.frame = CGRectOffset(txtRentalsHead.frame, 0, notesPixelsAdded);
    txtRentals.frame = CGRectOffset(txtRentals.frame, 0, notesPixelsAdded);


} else if (newTextViewHeight < textViewDefaultHeight) {
    notesPixelsRemoved = textViewDefaultHeight - newTextViewHeight;
    viewPixelsToBeRemoved += notesPixelsRemoved;

    txtDirectionsHead.frame = CGRectOffset(txtDirectionsHead.frame, 0, -notesPixelsRemoved);
    txtDirections.frame = CGRectOffset(txtDirections.frame, 0, -notesPixelsRemoved);
    txtRentalsHead.frame = CGRectOffset(txtRentalsHead.frame, 0, -notesPixelsRemoved);
    txtRentals.frame = CGRectOffset(txtRentals.frame, 0, -notesPixelsRemoved);

}   


//----------------------------------------------------------------------------    

txtDirections.text = _Campground.directions;
[self fitFrameToContent:txtDirections];
newTextViewHeight = txtDirections.contentSize.height;
if (newTextViewHeight > textViewDefaultHeight) {
    directionsPixelsAdded = newTextViewHeight - textViewDefaultHeight;
    viewPixelsToBeAdded += directionsPixelsAdded;

    txtRentalsHead.frame = CGRectOffset(txtRentalsHead.frame, 0, directionsPixelsAdded);
    txtRentals.frame = CGRectOffset(txtRentals.frame, 0, directionsPixelsAdded);


} else if (newTextViewHeight < textViewDefaultHeight) {
    directionsPixelsRemoved = textViewDefaultHeight - newTextViewHeight;
    viewPixelsToBeRemoved += directionsPixelsRemoved;

    txtRentalsHead.frame = CGRectOffset(txtRentalsHead.frame, 0, -directionsPixelsRemoved);
    txtRentals.frame = CGRectOffset(txtRentals.frame, 0, -directionsPixelsRemoved);

} 

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------    

txtRentals.text = _Campground.rentals;
[self fitFrameToContent:txtRentals];
newTextViewHeight = txtRentals.contentSize.height;
if (newTextViewHeight > textViewDefaultHeight) {
    rentalsPixelsAdded = newTextViewHeight - textViewDefaultHeight;
    viewPixelsToBeAdded += rentalsPixelsAdded;


} else if (newTextViewHeight < textViewDefaultHeight) {
    rentalsPixelsRemoved = textViewDefaultHeight - newTextViewHeight;
    viewPixelsToBeRemoved += rentalsPixelsRemoved;

} 

viewHeight += viewPixelsToBeAdded;
viewHeight -= viewPixelsToBeRemoved;
detailsView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, viewHeight);
scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, viewHeight);
}
```

Comment: Please post some more code so we have context. Also note that (although this is not related problem), UIKit sizes usually use CGFloat, not int, values. Also, what do you mean by "stops scrolling"? Do you mean the current scrolling animation is stopped, or that scrolling doesn't work anymore afterwards?

Comment: By stops scrolling I mean that I can't see anything past 480px.  The only thing that shows is what pops up in the iPhone default size.  Nothing below that will scroll.  I posted my populateLabels method.  I can include anything else you need.

Comment: The view itself is actually resizing. I added a background color and checked it.  It's the scrollView that won't resize.  I had the scrollView set to scrollView and detailsView at one point.  It wouldn't scroll otherwise.  Now I have the view itself set to detailsView and magically... it is still scrolling.  Now I just have to work out how to get the scrollView to resize correctly.

Comment: Anytime I statically set the viewHeight in scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, viewHeight); the scrollView will not scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A scrollView has two sizes: Its `frame`, which determines how large (and where) it is on the screen, and its `contentSize`, which determines how far it will scroll.

If `contentSize` is the same or smaller than `frame.size`, the scrollView will not scroll (because there is nothing to scroll to).

Usually, you'll want to set the `contentSize` of a scrollView to the size of the view(s) that you put into it.

Say you have a `UIImageView` that has a size of 1000x1000 points. Its `frame` will probably by `CGRectMake(0, 0, 1000, 1000)`. Say your ScrollView is a fullscreen on an iPhone in portrait orientation, so it has a frame of `CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)`. If you now set its `contentSize` to `CGSizeMake(1000, 1000)`, it will be able to scroll over all of the picture. If you make the `contentSize` a rectangle of 320 x 480, it won't scroll at all. And if you set the `contentSize` to 2000x2000, you will be able to scroll further than the picture.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're setting the same frame, which is much larger than the screen, on both the UIView and the UIScrollView? So the scroll view doesn't scroll because it's the same size as the view within it — there's nothing extra to show by scrolling.

Probably you want to leave the scroll view frame alone, so that the scroll view takes up the same amount of space on screen regardless of the size of its contents, and set the [`contentSize`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/contentSize) property. Similarly I'd expect you to want to pass 0 as the y coordinate for the view within the scrollview since view frames are relative to their parent.

Comment: This kind of worked.  It's scrolling again, but my view isn't shrinking down to where I need it to be.  I just can't figure out how to get that view to shrink up to where the content stops.

Comment: Should I be putting the scrollView within the view, then putting all of the objects within the scrollView?  The way I have it now... the scrollView is the top.  Within that is the actual view.  Then within the view are the objects (textViews, labels, buttons, etc).

Comment: Things you want to scroll should be children of the scroll view. Sadly it's not smart enough and there's no option for a scroll view to figure out its own contentSize based on its children, so you have to give it a bit of a nudge.

Comment: Ok. I guess that means I'm going about it the right way.  In my viewDidLoad I have scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 1475); My view should NEVER be larger than 1475px. So, should I set the scrollView to a smaller size?

Comment: Set the scroll view's frame to be the area you want it to occupy on screen. Set the content size as the name suggests. Your scroll view should therefore be significantly smaller than 1475 pt tall because the iPhone screen is significantly smaller than 1475 pts.